# Getting 16 least and most significant bits of an arbitrary length binary number

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

So the problem I am having is obtaining the least significant and most significant 16 bits of a number over 16 bits but not necessarily of any certain length.

If the number was an int which is 32 bits I believe I could just do something like:

```
int Num=0xFFFFFFFF
short most = (short)(Num & 0xFFFF0000);
short least =(short)(Num & 0x0000FFFF);
```

Result:

most=0xFFFF
least=0xFFFF

Which in theory should get me a short 16 bit number with the least and most significant bits. But the problem is I need to be able to do this for an arbitrary amount of bits number, so this approach will not work because it will change what I need to & the number with. Is there a better approach to getting these values?

It seems Like there would be a fairly simple way to do this, but I can't find anything online.

Thanks

Comment: What are you using to store numbers larger than 64 bits?  `BigInteger`?

Comment: @Jacob G.The numbers are coming in as hexidecimal representations. They can be any arbitrary size of bits.

Comment: Coming in... as what?  Java's `long` is 64 bits, so you'll have to use a `BigInteger` if you want anything bigger.

Comment: @Jacob G. It can be of any size, long, int, BigInteger etc. But I need to be able to be able to get the least and most significant 16 bits no matter what size the number is. I hope what I am trying to say is clear.

Comment: No, I understand.  The easiest solution is to use a `BigInteger` for every value, regardless of its size.  I can write a solution using one in a bit, if you don't mind.

Comment: If the number in hex is 0000000000000000000000000000000001234000000000000000005678, are the most significant 16 bits 0000 or 1234, and why? To implement this in a program you must have an algorithm, which is a fixed set of rules that always gives the correct answer (or a signalled failure).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 in that case 0000 would be the most significant 16 bits.

Comment: Are you _required_ to turn the input into some "legitimate" numeric representation and extract your MSBs and LSBs from that?  Or could you just read the hex digits as a string and pick off the first (MSBs) and last (LSBs) four characters with `.substring()`?

Comment: @Kevin Anderson I need the bits to become a numeric value. I don't know if there would be any way to turn the 16 bits represented as a string back into a short data type.

Comment: Would your opinion change if I told you that Yes, there is an easy way to turn a string of hex digits into a `short`?  Because, **Yes, there is a way**.

Answer (score 1):

Before the main subject. your code have wrong to get most.
you should shift right for 4.

```
short most = (short)((Num & 0xFFFF0000) >> 0x10);
```

---

I guess you want this approach.

```
// lenMost should be in 0 to 32
int[] divide(int target, int lenMost) {
    int MASK = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    int lenLeast = 32 - lenMost;

    int ret[] = new int[2]();
    // get most
    ret[0] = target & (MASK << lenLeast)
    ret[0] >>= lenLeast;
    // get least
    ret[1] = target & (MASK >> lenMost);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: So what if the number was more than 32 bits. Would this work? Because I don't have an upper bound on the number of bits the number I am doing these operations can be.

Comment: lol unvoted? It could be on long type too. So can be 64bits. But more bits be more complex.

Comment: No, OP needs `>> 16`. Shift is in bits. 16 bits corresponds to 4 places in hexadecimal (and vice versa).